# Cannot update as there is no primary key

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I have a WPF C# desktop app and I am using SQLite.

I have this model:

```
using SQLite;

[Table("Customer")]
public  class Customer
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }   
    public string CustomerRef { get; set; }
    public string SName { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }     
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Add1 { get; set; }
    public string Add2 { get; set; }
    public string Add3 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string PCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty( Add1))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(Add1.Trim());
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Add2))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(Add2.Trim());
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Add3))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(Add3.Trim());
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Town))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(Town.Trim());
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(County))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(County.Trim());
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PCode))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(PCode.Trim());
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Country))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(Country.Trim());
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

I add records to it - no problems. I try to update and I get a cannot update as there is no primary key.

This is the code:

```
var query = DB.Connector.Table<InformedWorkerModel.Customer>().Where(d => d.CustomerRef == customer.CustomerRef).FirstOrDefault();

if (query != null)
{
    query.Add1 = customer.Add1;
    query.Add2 = customer.Add2;
    query.Add3 = customer.Add3;
    query.Town = customer.Town;
    query.County = customer.County;
    query.Country = customer.Country;
    query.PCode = customer.PCode;
    query.ContactNo = customer.ContactNo;
    query.Email = customer.Email;
    query.FName = customer.FName;
    query.SName = customer.SName;
    DB.Connector.Update(query);
    return query;
}
```

It breaks on the driver code here and as you can see the quick watch shows no Primary Key on the field:

[image]

This is the screenshot where I initially created the database.

[image]

Any ideas please?

thanks

Comment: @marc_s yes I know that but my code and the data schema shows that a PK has already been set

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are doing good !

its seems like your data schema and your model is not mapped properly.

you can use attribute to mapped.

```
[Table("Customer")]
class Customer
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]    
    [Column(Name = "CustomerId")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    .......
}
```

Regards MK

Comment: Thanks, I did try that just before you posted and still got the same error :(

Comment: ok, I have just gone through the code, there is one function GetMapping(objtype). are you sure its working well ?

Comment: Hi, well that was what I stated in my question :) this is where it falls down.  This code is the download from Sql Lite nuget.I am now looking for a different driver

Comment: Yeah, then its good to check with different driver. Sqllite-net will be the good option :)  Thanks

Comment: Just some feedback. Change driver. All works now :) +1 for the suggestion

Comment: Thanks  Andrew Simpson see you soon with more tech games  :)

Comment: Hey Andrew, Hope you are doing good, if you have anything else for me please catch me on https://in.linkedin.com/in/mohsin-khan-5503801b. Thanks :)